# Radio button change event not working with RightClick error

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have radio buttons on click of which I want to perform some actions. The  change events are not working and it shows following error,

> Uncaught referenceerror: RightClick is not defined at onload

Here is my code that I am using, Please can I have some insight on this error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('In jQuery');
  $('#rblKnowAboutCourse').change(function() {
    console.log('In jQuery-On Click2-Sarvesh');
    if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
      $("#TextBox1").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("#TextBox1").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Click: <input type="radio" id="rblKnowAboutCourse" />
<input type="text" id="TextBox1" value="" placeholder="textbox" />
```

The error shows link for this line in html

`<body style="font-size:11px" onload="RightClick.init();">`

Here is the radios i am using,

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblKnowAboutCourse" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Height="30px" Width="708px"   TextAlign="Right" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem>Website</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Friends</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Your Company</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Online Ad</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add any relevant CSS, HTML or script. Your code works as advertised

Comment: It does not make sense to have ID on a radio and then test the value. IDs must be unique so each of them should have a known value

Comment: Why have onload instead of `$(function() {})` and what is in RightClick.init?

Comment: I am using .net platform and radiobuttonlist. So in that we can assign one id for all the radios in the group. @mplungjan . Onload is running over the whole project and many things are using this. So can't change this.

Comment: wrong in asp.net we can group radio button but they still have different id's

Comment: I am less into asp .net . Sorry for that. So how can we change this

Comment: you can chek here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Are you sure that you are not missing any `<script>` end tags?

Comment: yes I am sure. <script> is there @coder

Comment: can you post your full `<body>` code?

Comment: Yes, you will need to post the rendered HTML

Comment: I checked the code and removed the `onload="RightClick.init();">` now there is no error coming up but yes the functionality still not shiowing up on click event. One more thing, the same code is working fine on local machine

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the concern everyone has shown. My issue resolved just by changing the `id` to `class`.